# Meaning of ようにして in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 私はわざとＫの室を回避するようにして、こんな風に自分を往来の真中に見出したのです。

I found a few explanations of ようにして but it seems there's multiple meanings and/or the translation is context-dependent, so I'm not sure exactly how to translate it here. Here's some of my guesses:

"Making it so that I would avoid K's room" - this seems unlikely

"As if I was intentionally avoiding K's room" - seems better

"Making it a point to avoid K's room" - plausible

"Sort of avoiding K's room" - ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「私はわざとＫの室{へや}を回避{かいひ}するようにして、こんな風{ふう}に自分{じぶん}を往来{おうらい}の真中{まなか}に見出{みいだ}したのです。」

I think that the most natural interpretation of the first half would be:

"as if to intentionally avoid K's room"

because I feel it fairly unnatural, in this context, to interpret the 「ように（する）」 to denote a clear (or final) goal/purpose.  Rather, it appears to be used to describe (not so important) a process that leads to the end-result of the speaker finding himself in the middle of the street.

(As a Japanese-speaker, I am far more interested in the ***second*** half of this sentence because that is not something a monolingual Japanese-speaker would say in a natural setting.  It sounds as if it were translated from a European language.  I would say that this author was proficient in one.)

Answer (score 0):

In general, 「〜ようにする 」 means that the subject is doing something such that  〜 will happen.

So in this case, the subject 私 is doing something (the something is implied in this case) so that he will be avoiding K's room. In other words, 私 is taking measures to avoid K's room.

The て形 has a lot of uses, all of which show that the two clauses are linked somehow with the first either coinciding with our preceding the second. I personally think that just remembering that is enough to make sense of it in most cases. <strike>I do believe however that one of the uses of the て形 when joining clauses in to show that the second was unexpected given the first.</strike> *Edit: I think this is just a sequential use*.

> 私はわざとＫの室を回避するようにして、こんな風に自分を往来の真中に見出したのです

<strike>I was making every effort to avoid K's room but in the process I ended up running into him in the street/hall</strike>.

*This translation was kindly pointed out to me in the comments as incorrect. I misunderstood the meaning of 自分を見出す. A more accurate translation is below.*

I was making every effort to avoid K's room and in the process, I found myself in the middle of the street.

I used "every" to strengthen the effort that I think わざと adds. Including "on purpose" is redundant in the English I think.

こんな風に is "in the process" though "in this manner" might be more accurate.

If anyone believes I am incorrect anywhere, I welcome criticism.

Comment: How do you get "running into **him**" at all?

Comment: @l'électeur I thought 自分 was referring to K and reasoned that 見出す meant to suddenly see. "Running into" is almost definitely too figurative for 見出す as you pointed out. Is there any ambiguity about who 自分 refers to and if not, what part of the sentence is making you so certain (for my own learning)? Thanks. I'll edit this answer in a little.